Show that $P(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n=-\infty)=1$
Let $X_1,\dots, X_n,\dots $ be a sequence of independent random variables such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $P(X_n=n^2)=1/n^2$ and $P(X_n=-1)=1-1/n^2$. Show that $$P(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n=-\infty)=1$$

Since we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=n^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2<\infty$, then by Borel-Cantelli Lemma
$$
P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=n^2\})=0
$$
Similarly, since we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=-1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-1/n^2)=\infty$, then by Borel-Cantelli Lemma
$$
P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=-1\})=1
$$
How to conclude the result from here?

From the first application of Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we get
$$
     P\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{k = n}^\infty \{X_k = -1\}\right) = 1 - P(\limsup\{X_n = n^2\}) = 1
$$
Let $\omega \in \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{k = n}^\infty \{X_n = -1\}$. Then, there exists $n_0(\omega) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_k(\omega) = -1 \ \forall k \ge n_0(\omega)$. But this means that
$$
    \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n(\omega) = -\infty
$$
Therefore,
$$
    P\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n = -\infty\right) \ge P\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{k = n}^\infty \{X_k = -1\}\right) = 1
$$

But why your result is contradiction with the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma? I mean that should be $P(\limsup {X_n=-1})=1$, right? Here you get $P(\liminf {X_n=-1})=1$?

@H.YDuan Since ${\liminf {X_n = -1}} \subseteq {\limsup {X_n = -1}}$, we have, $1 = P(\limsup {X_n = -1}) \ge P(\liminf {X_n = -1}) = 1$. Where is the contradiction ?
